# Prove that $\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{x+2}{x^2+1} = \frac{3}{2}$

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

I am required to prove the following limit using the epsilon-delta definition:

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x+2}{x^2+1}=\frac{3}{2}$$

So, ($\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0)[0<\vert x-1\vert<\delta \implies\vert\frac{x+2}{x^2+1}-\frac{3}{2}\vert<\epsilon]$

Below is my working on getting the $\delta$ that I need:

$\vert\frac{x+2}{x^2+1}-\frac{3}{2}\vert\le\vert\frac{x+2}{x^2+1}\vert+\frac{3}{2}=\frac{\vert x+2 \vert}{\vert x^2+1 \vert}+\frac{3}{2}$ (Triangle Inequality)

But I know that $x^2+1\ge1$ for all values of $x$, so I can say that $\frac{\vert x+2 \vert}{\vert x^2+1 \vert}+\frac{3}{2}\le\vert x-1+3\vert+\frac{3}{2}\le \vert x-1\vert +3 + \frac{3}{2}<\delta+\frac{9}{2}$

So for every $\epsilon$, I choose $\delta=\epsilon-\frac{9}{2}$, then:$$0<\vert x-1\vert<\delta \implies\vert\frac{x+2}{x^2+1}-\frac{3}{2}\vert \le \vert\frac{x+2}{x^2+1}\vert+\frac{3}{2}\le\vert x+2\vert+\frac{3}{2}\le\vert x-1+3\vert+\frac{3}{2}\le \vert x-1\vert +3 + \frac{3}{2}<\delta+\frac{9}{2}=\epsilon$$

Am I doing this right? Is there something wrong to assume that $x^2+1\ge1$ for all values of $x$?

Comment: If $\epsilon = 0.5$ then your $\delta$ is negative, so that is a warning you are doing something wrong. Also you are setting $|x+2| < \delta$ when it needs to be $|x-1|$

Comment: My bad, just made the edit, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: You need to choose $\delta>0$.

Comment: Right now $\epsilon = \delta + \frac{9}{2}$ where $\delta > 0$. So your expression won't work for any $\epsilon < \frac{9}{2}$. I think this will be easier if you first find a common denominator between $\frac{x+2}{x^2+1}$ and $\frac{3}{2}$ instead of using triangle inequality right away.

Comment: This proof would also show that the limit is 66. Not sure what edit you made, but you still haven't found a $\delta>0$ for any $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Using the triangle inequality right away is the super problematic part here. You are supposed to have $\frac{x+2}{x^2+1}$ and $\frac{3}{2}$ cancel each other out, which does happen with $\vert\frac{x+2}{x^2+1}-\frac{3}{2}\vert$  but doesn't happen with $\vert\frac{x+2}{x^2+1}\vert+\frac{3}{2}$, i.e. you inequality is too weak. Throughout your calculations (so long as everything is continuous) you should be able to plug in the limit and get zero. If you can't, you have messed up.

Comment: Any hints on getting the two terms to cancel each other out? Tried combining both fractions so far but it seems to be not working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|\frac{x+2}{x^2 +1} - \frac{3}{2}| = |\frac{-3x^2 + 2x + 1}{2(x^2+1)}|$

Using your same logic about $x^2 + 1$, we can bound it from above this way:

$|\frac{-3x^2 + 2x + 1}{2(x^2+1)}| \leq |\frac{-3x^2+2x+1}{2}| \leq |-3x^2+2x+1| = |3x^2-2x-1| = |(3x+1)(x-1)|$

We're looking for any $\delta > 0$ that will make this expression less than $\epsilon$. Our main problem here is that we need a way to bound the expression $3x+1$. We can do this by letting $\delta \leq 1$. This is allowed because even if we can find a $\delta > 1$ that works, any $\delta$ less than it will work as well. So, if $\delta \leq 1$ then:

$|x-1| < 1 \implies -1 < x-1 < 1 \implies 0 < x < 2 \implies 1 < 3x+1 < 7$

Now we can bound our limit expression from above. If $\delta \leq 1$ and $|x-1| < \delta$ then:

$|(3x+1)(x-1)| < 7 \delta$

Which is less than epsilon if $\delta =\frac{\epsilon}{7}$

You might think you're done, and $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{7}$. But remember our solution depended on $\delta \leq 1$. So what if $\epsilon = 100$? For this reason, we need to take the minimum of 1 and $\frac{\epsilon}{7}$. So the final answer is $\delta = \min\{\frac{\epsilon}{7}, 1\}$

Comment: Many thanks! Its clearer to me now!

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:)**

Notice that you can't **never** conclude from 
$$|f(x)-\ell|\leq|f(x)|+|\ell|<\epsilon~~~~,~~~~~\ell\neq0$$
obtained by triangle inequality, **a** limit yield.

Answer (score 2):

$\large{\vert\frac{x+2}{x^2+1}-\frac{3}{2}\vert=\vert\frac{2x+4-3x^2-3}{2(x^2+1)}\vert=\vert\frac{(x-1)(-3x-1)}{2(x^2+1)}\vert}$ Can you take it further?